# Import large amount of MySQL data to Hadoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, import

I am planning to use a stack which uses Hadoop, Hive and Impala for analysing big data. I have the setup ready and now I am trying to import data from a MySQL table. The table size is more than 500 GB and I am planning to use Sqoop as follows :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote_host_ip/database_name --username user_name -P --table table_name --hive-import --compression-codec=snappy --as-parquetfile --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse -m 1
```

Is there any other better method for doing this import as this involves transferring 500 GB of data over the network. Is it possible to compress the data anyway and import it to Hive, so Impala can be used to query it ?

Comment: I used to just export the database as csv, pipe it through gzip and into HDFS. I give a cookie to the person who get's this into a shell script :)

Comment: MySQL supports compression "on the wire" with `jdbc:mysql://remote_host_ip/database_name?useCompression=true` cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html and http://torstens-tech-blog.blogspot.com/2012/08/client-compression-with-mysql-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is the best approach. Its very efficient in bulk loading.

Do read about the [MySQL Hadoop Applier](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-hadoop-applier.html) which is designed to perform real-time replication of events between MySQL and Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "-m 4" instead of "-m 1". This would allow MySql data to be imported in parallel fashion i.e. instead of using 1 mapper transferring 500GB, 4 mappers will be used to transfer the data in parallel(125 GB using each mapper).

Answer (score 0):

SQOOP will be better to import 500 GB of data into columnar HDFS format which is Parquet file format. But you can use '-m 12' which makes more parallel mappers to import.